# Как создать регистрацию для localhost на mac os

Tags: php, javascript, apache, sqlite3, регистрация

Добрый день, пишу проект (на macbook) с преподавателем, сайт с созданием заметок и, естественно, системой регистрации. В моем распоряжении есть:

- Предустановленный в os x **apache2**
- Предустановленный там же **Python 2.7**
- Настроенный **SQLite3** и его браузер
- Список сказанных преподавателем слов с содержанием "*mod_python, json, flask*" и т.д.
- Достойное, но не отличное знание **html, css, javascript, php,** работе сайтов в принципе и функционировании сервера (локалхост как минимум запустил без проблем)

  Но недели две как не могу настроить систему регистрации с передачей информации из html страницы ввода информации о пользователе именно в **SQLite3**. Все работают с **mysql**, и через нее и php без проблем все передается, но мне нужно именно с моим набором - **js**/**php**/**python** и **SQLite3**.
  Если кто-то знает, занимался этим, или просто в курсе моего вопроса, буду очень признателен, если дадите мне информацию по этому поводу, источники, ссылки или рекомендации

Comment: **php** и **Python** из разных галактик.

Comment: В плане того, что мне довольно навязчиво втирают регистрацию именно с помощью его. Разницу я понимаю, но метод подойдет уже любой, так как сроки горят, а дело стоит

Comment: Советую посмотреть это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJRL_MKoX9M .

Comment: подключите auth0 :)

Comment: За видео спасибо, полезное, не спорю. Но все таки там парень использует windows и open server, с которым, как я читал в источниках, любая задача выполняется на раз два. Но в том и суть, что я пишу на mac, где нет open server, и поэтому все чуть усложняется. Хотя информацию для себя я вынес. Про auth0 изучаю

Comment: Да и phpmyadmin работает только с mysql, а его ставить мне пока ни необходимости нет, ни времени на изучение (глобальная штука, все таки)